# Add Question Mark to ARFF Using Java code

Tags: java, weka, arff

I have a code to prepare an ARFF file for Weka. It's going to be used to classify data using an already-built model in j48 algorithm.

In ARFF file, i need to put question mark at the last column so that Weka tries to classify the data. I have this code:

```
        ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();
        classVal.add("C1");
        classVal.add("C2");
        atts.add(new Attribute("a"));
        atts.add(new Attribute("b"));
        atts.add(new Attribute("c"));
        atts.add(new Attribute("d"));
        atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@", classVal));
        Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstances", atts, 0);
        dataRaw.setClassIndex(dataRaw.numAttributes() - 1);
        double[] instanceValue1 = new double[] { p.getIncludedLength(), p.getTimestampSeconds()};
        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));
        ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
        saver.setInstances(dataRaw);
        saver.setFile(new File(path3));
        saver.setDestination(new File(path3));
        saver.writeBatch();
```

So, as the last element there should be a ?, which is not a double value. How can I add it?

```
double[] instanceValue1 = new double[] { p.getIncludedLength(), p.getTimestampSeconds(), ?};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DenseInstance di = new DenseInstance(3);  // Sets all 3 values to missing
di.setValue(0, p.getIncludedLength());
di.setValue(1, p.getTimestampSeconds());
```

Or if you really have a ton of values in an array, you could use a zero value as a placeholder and try setMissing()

```
double[] instanceValue1 = new double[] { p.getIncludedLength(), p.getTimestampSeconds(), 0.0}
DenseInstance di = new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1);
di.setMissing(2);
```